# Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 2.3 and facing this error since 2 days. Full Error log is given below

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/E:/Android/android-studio-ide-2.3-windows/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3/gradle-2.3.pom
    file:/E:/Android/android-studio-ide-2.3-windows/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3/gradle-2.3.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3/gradle-2.3.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3/gradle-2.3.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

Comment: In your top level `build.gradle` file you are missing a `0` at the end of the dependency `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.` - it should read `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0` - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/

Comment: Thank you so much. I edited it manually because of that I forget and couldn't notice the error meaning.